# Merge columns of data from multiple text files by row from each seperate file using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I have output from a numerical modelling code.  I needed to extract a specific value from a series of files.  I used the following code to get it (I derived this from an example that would extract IP addresses from logfiles):

```
$input_path = ‘C:\_TEST\Input_PC\out5.txt’
$output_file = ‘C:\_TEST\Output_PC_All\out5.txt’
$regex = ‘\bHEAD(.+)\s+[\-]*\d{1,3}\.\d{6,6}\s?\b’
select-string -Path $input_path -Pattern $regex -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value } > $output_file
```

So I now have got a number of text files which contain measurements (the number of files may be variable, currently there are 50) with one column of numeric data (with a number of rows which currently equals 7302 but which may vary depending on the length of the time series modelled) and which may be positive or negative as per the example data below.

*Note a semicolon preceding the text indicates that what follows is a comment I am using to explain the order of the dataset and does not appear in the data to be processed...*

**out1.txt**

> -1.000000                         ; 1st line of out1.txt
>    2.000000                         ; 2nd line of out1.txt
>   -3.000000                         ; 3rd line of out1.txt
>   ...
>   5.000000                          ; nth line of out1.txt

**out2.txt**

> -1.200000                         ; 1st line of out2.txt
>   -2.200000                         ; 2nd line of out2.txt
>    3.200000                         ; 3rd line of out2.txt
>   ...
>   -5.20000                          ; nth line of out2.txt

**outn.txt**

> 1.300000                          ; 1st line of outn.txt
>   -2.300000                         ; 2nd line of outn.txt
>   -3.300000                         ; 3rd line of outn.txt
>   ...
>   10.300000                         ; nth line of outn.txt

I need to merge them into a single text file (for this example lets call it "Combined_Output.txt") using Powershell with the data ordered so that the first row of values from the differing output files appear first, then repeat this for row 2 and so on as below:

**Combined_Output.txt**

> -1.000000                         ; 1st line of out1.txt
>   -1.200000                         ; 1st line of out2.txt
>   1.300000                          ; 1st line of outn.txt
>   2.000000                          ; 2nd line of out1.txt
>   -2.200000                         ; 2nd line of out2.txt
>   -2.300000                         ; 2nd line of outn.txt
>   -3.000000                         ; 3rd line of out1.txt
>   3.200000                          ; 3rd line of out2.txt
>   -3.300000                         ; 3rd line of outn.txt
>   ...
>    5.000000                         ; nth line of out1.txt
>   -5.200000                         ; nth line of out2.txt
>    10.300000                        ; nth line of outN.txt

Just to say that I'm very new to this sort of thing so I hope that the explanation above makes sense and also to say any help that you can provide would be much appreciated.

**EDIT**
Having now run the models, when using this code for the large data files created, there seems to be an issue of sorting of the imported data.  This seems to occur primarily when there are repeated values for example the second row of data from each outfile has been combined in the following order by the script. It looks like there is some sorting based on the value of the data and not just based on the out file name:

> Value ; out file text number
>   -1.215809 ; 1
>   -0.480543 ; 18
>   -0.480541 ; 19
>   -0.48054 ; 2
>   -0.480539 ; 20
>   -0.480538 ; 21
>   -0.480537 ; 22
>   -0.480536 ; 23
>   -0.480535 ; 24
>   -0.480534 ; 25
>   -0.480534 ; 26
>   -0.480688 ; 10
>   -0.480533 ; 27
>   -0.480532 ; 3
>   -0.480776 ; 4
>   -0.48051 ; 5
>   -0.48051 ; 6
>   -0.48051 ; 7
>   -0.48051 ; 8
>   -0.48051 ; 9
>   -0.48051 ; 11
>   -0.48051 ; 12
>   -0.48051 ; 13

Comment: This should not be to terribly difficult. What have you tried so far? Should be able to get all text files into memory and with a counter create a new file of each corresponding line in the files. SO works better if you show some coding effort.

Comment: To get the data to a stage where it was a single column in a text file I used the following: `$input_path = ‘C:\_TEST\Input_PC\out5.txt’
$output_file = ‘C:\_TEST\Output_PC_All\out5.txt’
$regex = ‘\bHEAD(.+)\s+[\-]*\d{1,3}\.\d{6,6}\s?\b’
select-string -Path $input_path -Pattern $regex -AllMatches | % { $_.Matches } | % { $_.Value } > $output_file`  as the output from the model is a fairly complex logfile.  I've never done any programming before approx Monday this week.  The above I bodged together from an example that was used to extract IP addresses from logfiles.

Comment: I should add that I meant powershell programmiong.  This is how I might attempt to solve it in the code I am used to "Fish language for ITASCA FLAC"  However I am not sure it is actually possible in FISH. Also there are far fewer people working with this language than things like powershell so it is difficult to get help.  See below for example:

Comment: `set log name 'C:\PWP_Output.txt'  
set log off  Def Arrange 
Max_file_No = 50   
Max_line_no = 7202   
Loop line_no(1,Max_line_no)   
Loop out_name(1,Max_file_No)    
 Out_file_namer = 'out'+ string(out_name)+'.txt'   
 float cc   
  array cc (Max_file_No)  
  status = open(Out_file_namer, IO_READ, IO_ASCII)  
 status = read(cc,line_no)  
 Pore_pressure_val = parse(cc(line_no),1)  
 command  
 set log on  
 print Pore_pressure_val  
 set log off  
 end_command  
 end_loop  
end_loop   
end  
Arrange`

Comment: Update your question using the edit button. Long code snippets in comments looks horrible

Comment: Are all the files outn.txt the same length?

Comment: I will test with more files and larger data samples and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like I might have over complicated this answer but lets see how we do. Consider the following dummy data similar to your samples

```
Out1.txt    Out2.txt    Out3.txt
-0.40000    0.800000    4.100000
3.500000    0.300000    -0.90000
-2.60000    0.800000    2.200000
0.500000    1.800000    -1.40000
3.600000    1.800000    1.400000
40000000    -0.70000    1.500000
```

The file contents are arranged side by side for answer brevity and to help understand the output. The code is as follows:

```
$allTheFiles = @()
Get-ChildItem c:\temp\out*.txt | ForEach-Object{
    $allTheFiles += ,(Get-Content $_.FullName)
}

For ($lineIndex=0; $lineIndex -lt $allTheFiles[0].Count; $lineIndex++){
    For($fileIndex=0; $fileIndex -lt $allTheFiles.Count; $fileIndex++){
        $allTheFiles[$fileIndex][$lineIndex]
    }
} | Out-File -FilePath c:\temp\file.txt -Encoding ascii
```

Gather all out*.txt files the code creates an array of arrays which are the file contents themselves. Using nested `For` loops cycle though each single file outputting one line from each file at a time. While I am having a hard time being clear on what is happening if you compare the sample data to the output you should see that the first line or every file is outputted together followed by the next line...etc.

This code will produce the following output

```
-0.40000
0.800000
4.100000
3.500000
0.300000
-0.90000
-2.60000
0.800000
2.200000
0.500000
1.800000
-1.40000
3.600000
1.800000
1.400000
40000000
-0.70000
1.500000
```

**Caveats**

The code assumes that all files are of the same size. The number of lines is determined by the first file. If other files contain more data it would be lost in this model.

Comment: Matt, thank you very much. Just to help explain why I wanted this, each value represents a pore water pressure at the near surface in a hydrological modelling code in response to meteorological changes. Each "out.txt" file represent one surface element in the grid, each subsequent line represents the new value for the next time increment (daily).  The model is run for a prescribed time period (7302 days approx 20 years) hence each out.txt will always have the same number of rows of data. I need to apply the values to a geomechanics modelling code to look at the effect on slope stability.

Comment: Also I am going to attempt to edit your code so it outputs into a specified text file.  I am hoping I can bodge something together from yours and the first piece of code. Once again thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @sbdw1 i added an output line in my answer.

Comment: I am getting the following error.                         `An empty pipe element is not allowed.
At line:5 char:4
+ } | <<<<  Out-File -FilePath C:\_TEST\Output_PC_ALL\PWP.txt -Encoding ascii
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EmptyPipeElement`

Comment: @sbdw1 The error says line 5. If you copied my code exactly that error should have been on line 9. It sounds line `$allTheFiles` contained no data.

Comment: That seemed to be an issue with copying and pasting the code into Notepad++ and then into Powershell.  I've now copied it directly in to Powershell ISE and it still generates the error (on line 10)   `An empty pipe element is not allowed.
At C:\Users\Pete\Desktop\Test.ps1:10 char:4
+ } | <<<<  Out-File -filepath c:\temp\file.txt -Encoding ascii
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EmptyPipeElement` If I type $allTheFiles directly into Powershell it prints the values to screen after showing the above error message.

Comment: Further to the above, I've now realised that when using Powershell ISE I can just copy the printed data out of the output window as it will display the whole output whereas Powershell would truncate it...

Comment: This code still works for me. You will have to do some debugging. What happens when you remove the `| Out-file ...` cmdlet. Are you moving the Out-File to a new line? My code has Out-File on line 9? Please try and copy my code exactly. It is important that the `Out-File`  call be on the same line and the last `}` from ForEach like `} | Out-File -FilePath`

Comment: Matt,  I've finally run the hydrological models but now have found a problem.  When using the script for the actual data files, as there are more than 9, it doesn't open them in the correct order (instead it opens them in the following order 1,10,11...19,2,20...).  I've got round this by renaming the files so that file out2 is now out10 etc. 
Another problem which I have not been able to solve is that the above order that the data is extracted also seems to be being effected by the actual value of the data. Where several output files have identical data values, the order will change. eg below

Comment: I follow the first comment. The files are being sorted alphabetically. We can work with that if it is an issue. However if you are trying to show me code or data edit the question so I can read it better.

Comment: where first value is data and second is the out file number it was extracted from...  `-1.215809 ; 1  
-0.480543 ; 18  
-0.480541 ; 19  
-0.48054 ; 2  
-0.480539 ; 20  
-0.480538 ; 21  
-0.480537 ; 22  
-0.480536 ; 23  
-0.480535 ; 24  
-0.480534 ; 25  
-0.480534 ; 26  
-0.480688 ; 10  
-0.480533 ; 27  
-0.480532 ; 3  
-0.480776 ; 4  
-0.48051 ; 5  
-0.48051 ; 6  
-0.48051 ; 7  
-0.48051 ; 8  
-0.48051 ; 9  
-0.48051 ; 11  
-0.48051 ; 12  
-0.48051 ; 13`

Comment: Sorry Matt, just seen your comment.  Will edit original question to better explain...